# Connect 2 images with a line in HTML. Django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I'm working on this project which requires a sort of timeline for 3 major events.

I represent each of the events with a checkmark image. (and depending on whether these events occured correctly, the checkmark appears in green yellow or red). So these images are generated dynamically using Django template language.

Now I want to connect these 3 images using a line or arrow from the first to the second and second to the third.

It should look something like this: [Click here to see the image](http://i.1dl.us/v24.png)

Now a quick and dirty way would be to simply add those grey bars as images and float the 5 images together.
But that would raise resolution-scaling issues.

Is there a way to draw this line dynamically in some way?
Please help!

EDIT: I have to use this for IE 7 etc, so cannot use HTML5.
Also, custom Python-graphics plugins would be overkill I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got this done in a hacky sort of way..

I used 5 table cells (you could use divs too, my particular application required tables) for each of the 3 checkmark images and 2 cells between each checkmarks to draw the bars/lines..

I drew the bars inside the 2 cells using..

```
<td style="background-position:center center !important; 
background:url('{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/bar-grey.png') ; 
background-repeat:repeat-x; width:300px !important;  
padding-left:0px !important; padding-right:0px !important; ">
```

Now this would not touch the circle-image-checkmarks and there were breaks in the bar.
So I set a fixed width of 100px for the checkmark cells. 
And used similar code as above to connect the bar to the circle by applying it as a background for the circle-cell.

One of the challenges I had was that in some cases I had different color bars on each side of the middle circle. Also for the first and last circles, the bar had only to be drawn of the right and left-halves respectively.

So I followed [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446168/css-how-to-create-a-table-cell-with-a-two-colour-background) and managed to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Either of [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) or [Pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) can let you draw those. Just create a separate view to use in your `img`, and have it return the PNG data.

Comment: Is this necessary and not overkill? I thought this could be achieved using some js/jquery and css.
Thank you for your inputs though, appreciate it.

Comment: You probably could. But then you're depending on the browser to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of drawing a line on a canvas element and then rendering two images on top of it.

The Ignacio is correct however, you will run into browser issues as I don't believe IE < 9 supports canvas.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
canvas {
    width: 600;
    height: 200;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var i = new Image();
    i.src = 'https://www.balancedpayments.com/images/balanced.png';
    i.onload = function () { ctx.drawImage(i, 100 - i.width / 2, 100 - i.height / 2); };

    var j = new Image();
    j.src = 'https://www.balancedpayments.com/images/balanced.png';
    j.onload = function () { ctx.drawImage(j, 300 - i.width / 2, 100 - i.height / 2); };

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
    ctx.lineTo(500, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, HTML5's <canvas> would be a good solution but I need this to run on IE 7, etc. too!
Thanks though, I'll definitely try this out..